# animate an absolute positioned Divbox on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I try to animate an absolute positioned Div on click. The Tags are divs with #menu and the HTML5 Tag nav. The nav is kinda the wrapper of the #menu boxes. Everything is position absolute.

This is the CSS Code:

```
nav  { 
    top:50%; 
    left:50%; 
    position: absolute; 
    margin-top:-31.5px; 
    margin-left:-150px; 
    height: 63px; 
    width: 300px; 
    border: 1px solid '#f2f2f2; 
    background: '#333333; top: 400px 
}

menu1 { 
    height: 63px; 
    width: 75px; 
    float: left; 
    background-image: url(../img/1.png); 
}
```

The jQuery is:

```
$('#menu1').click(function() {
    $('nav').animate({
        top: '+=50px',
    }, 
    5000, 
    function() {

    });
});
```

But its not working. After a Click on the "#menu1" the nav should slide up to the wrappers top. Is that possible?
Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Your menu1 is missing the hash in the CSS, as it is an element with `id="menu1"` and not `<menu1>`:

```
#menu1 { 
    height: 63px; 
    width: 75px; 
    float: left; 
    background-image: url(../img/1.png); 
}
```

Comment: Correct, <nav> is a valid HTML5 tag.

Comment: is it even valid for the jQuery function? Or is that '#nav' missing like the other Answer said?

Comment: The ID at #menu1 is given, it was my fault. 'nav' is an HTML5 Tag and I guess its valid for jQuery.

In the End, it should be simply like that.
http://s7.directupload.net/images/110705/9hb8tq9n.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you missed or its not there , both of them are wrong

if it is id is should have # or if it is class it should have dot "."

you are missing # in your jquery too.

```
change this $('nav') to $('#nav')

 $('#nav').animate({
        top: '+=50px',
    }, 
    5000, 
    function() {

    });



  #nav  { 
        top:50%; 
        left:50%; 
        position: absolute; 
        margin-top:-31.5px; 
        margin-left:-150px; 
        height: 63px; 
        width: 300px; 
        border: 1px solid '#f2f2f2; 
        background: '#333333; top: 400px 
    }

    #menu1 { 
        height: 63px; 
        width: 75px; 
        float: left; 
        background-image: url(../img/1.png); 
    }
```

Comment: But "nav" is an id like body in html5. I guess 'nav' is right and '#nav' is wrong?

Comment: @dustin , i am sorry , i was thinking that like a div tag or so